# Turing machines with read-only stack and two stacks

Tags: computer-science, automata, turing-machines

I am new to turing machines. I am stuck at how to prove this problem?

Consider we have only read-only tape and two stacks. Prove that this machine can accept PDA, NPDA and normal Turing machines with one tape.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try asking this question on cs.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to prove that the machine can simulate a Turing machine, because TMs can simulate PDAs and NPDAs.

Hint: the two stacks pretend to be the tape of the TM you're simulating. One of the stacks contains symbols to the left of the tape head. The other contains symbols to the right of the tape head.  You can make it seem like you have infinite tape to the right, even if the stack only contains finitely many symbols at any given time.